# Questions on using imported component

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular js 2. Have been going through the tutorials and trying things out but stucked on one issue below. Would anyone know on this?

Below is my code

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Items} from './test_items';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`        
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
                        <span>{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Test';
}
```

test_items.ts

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

var HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { "id": 11, "name": "Mr. Nice" },
  { "id": 12, "name": "Narco" },
  { "id": 13, "name": "Bombasto" },
  { "id": 14, "name": "Celeritas" },
  { "id": 15, "name": "Magneta" },
  { "id": 16, "name": "RubberMan" },
  { "id": 17, "name": "Dynama" },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Dr IQ" },
  { "id": 19, "name": "Magma" },
  { "id": 20, "name": "Tornado" }
];

export class Items {
  public heroes = HEROES;
}
```

The list of heroes does not get displayed out as expected. Is there a restriction from getting the list from another component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Items,Hero} from './comp';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template:`        
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
                        <span>{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'Test';
  heroes:Hero[];

  constructor(items:Items)
  {
    this.heroes = items.heroes;
  }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [Items]);
```

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks for this but would prefer the above solution which is easier

Comment: @Ruster in the above solution you are instantiating the object for getting items, but what i had give is proper angular2 way which uses dependency injection.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The view of the component iterates over the arrary `heroes` of the component. But there is no such array at all. The only thing that the component has is a title.

The fact that a completely unrelated class `Items` happens to have a fields named `heroes` is irrelevant. So is the fact that you imported `Items` in the component.

Importing doesn't mean that all the fields of `Items` become fields of `AppComponent`. It simply means that the compiler and the runtime know where to look for the `Items` class when compiling/executing the code. But since `AppComponent` doesn't use the class `Items`, the import is useless.

Comment: Thanks! I also, tried using Items.heroes but that does not show the list as well. In that case, how can I show the heroes lists from Items Components?

Comment: heroes is an instance field, not a static field. You need an instance to access its heroes: `let items = new Items(); console.log(items.heroes)`. So, to access the items heroes from the view, have an instance field `public items = new Items();` in your component, and use `#hero of items.heroes` in the view.